# Expected length of a sequence that contains all words of a given length.

Tags: probability

Fix some alphabet $\Sigma$ and a positive integer $n$.  What is the expected number of random letters drawn from $\Sigma$ until all length-$n$ words are present?

For example, let $\Sigma = \{0,1\}.$  Then the string "10" contains all possible 1-letter words, ie "0" and "1".  The expected length for a random string is simply the coupon-collector problem with 2 cards... so the expected length is 3.

But it's more complicated when words can overlap.  For the same alphabet and $n=2$ we can see that the string "00110" has all 2-letter words, and I claim that's the shortest string that does. But what's the expected length of a random string that contains all four strings "00", "01", "10", and "11"?  The usual coupon-collector approach doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Related (counting minimum length instead of expected length) : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48808/shortest-sequence-containing-all-permutations and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15510/

Comment: I know I'm getting old when a related question was asked by me and I have no memory of asking it.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland I think that's the same ref leonbloy cited at the end of his answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Well, here's a solution, but it's not pretty.

As noted in my answer to
[Cover time chess board (king)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286739/cover-time-chess-board-king/286871#286871),
 there is *in principle* no difficulty in answering this question.
Calculating the expected cover 
time of the set of patterns $\cal S$ reduces to calculating the expected hitting time 
 of every possible non-empty subset $A$ of $\cal S$:

$$\mathbb{E}(\text{cover time})=\sum_A (-1)^{|A|-1} \mathbb{E}(T_A)\tag1$$

These hitting times are defined by $T_A=\inf(n\geq 0: X_n\in A)$.
These, in turn, can be found using a technique from Section 14.3 (Patterns III) 
of *Problems and Snapshots from the World of Probability* by Blom, Holst, and Sandell.

For instance with strings of length two we find
$$\mathbb{E}(T_{00,01,10,11})=2$$
$$\mathbb{E}(T_{00,01,10})=\mathbb{E}(T_{01,10,11})=5/2,\quad \mathbb{E}(T_{00,10,11})= \mathbb{E}(T_{00,01,11})=9/4$$
$$\mathbb{E}(T_{00,01})=\mathbb{E}(T_{00,10})=\mathbb{E}(T_{00,11})=\mathbb{E}(T_{01,10})=\mathbb{E}(T_{01,11})=\mathbb{E}(T_{10,11})=3$$
$$\mathbb{E}(T_{00})=\mathbb{E}(T_{11})=6,\quad \mathbb{E}(T_{01})=\mathbb{E}(T_{10})=4$$

Plugging all this information into (1), we find that the expected time 
to see all four patterns $00,01,10$, and $11$ is $19/2=9.5$.

Just for fun, I've calculated the expected time to see all eight patterns of length three to be ${89259/ 3640}= 24.5217$.

Answer (score 2):

*Update*: This is wrong - sorry, I misread the question, I understood that we were interested in getting all permutations (words with different letters).

---

For $n=2$ it's not hard to see that the expected length is 5 : expected length of first run (2) + expected length of second run (2) +  1. For $n>2$ it seems more difficult.

Applying the coupon-collector approach, one would say that the expected number of tries to collect the $m$-th permutation (among $n!$ permutations) is $1/p_m = n^n/(n!-m)$ and so

$$E_n = n^n \left( \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \dots +\frac{1}{n!} \right)=n^n H({n!})  $$

This, of course, is an approximation, because it assumes that each new letter of the sequence gives a new $n$-word, independent of the previous ones; but the overlapping must introduce some dependence. It's not clear, however, the sense of this dependence. And this, together with the fact that for large $n$ the probability of a word being a permutation (even for the "first coupon") is low, leads to think that the approximation might be reasonable. Numerical evidence sees to agree.

Eg: for $E_5 = 16777.7$, empirically I get $\approx 16730$.

---

Update: Actually we are not interested in getting all permutations ($n!$) but all words ($n^n$). The above coupen-collector approach can also be applied, giving us $E_n \approx n^n H(n^n) \sim n^{n+1} \log(n) $, but the independence assumption is less justified, and the result less precise.

We can regard each word as a vertex on a directed graph, or state of a doubly-stochastic Markov chain ($n$ equal non null entries in each row-column). We are asking then about the **cover time** of this chain. This could help to locate material. For example, [here (section 2.3)](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~aldous/Papers/me47.pdf) it is stated as a known result (but references are missing) the asympotic

$$E_n \sim n^n \log(n)$$

Also, see [here](http://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/markovmixing.pdf) (page 11.3.3).

Comment: Could you expand on the argument leading to mean length 5 when n=2?

Comment: @Did: You can easily get that result, only by misreading the problem statement ;-)  updated

Comment: Kudos for your sense of humour. (Unrelated: I am once again somewhat mystified by the way votes work on this site...).

Comment: Well, everyone seems predisposed to vote up any answer from a +5K user.