# What is the shortest sequence that contains every permutation of $1..n$?

Tags: combinatorics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the shortest string that contains all permutations of an alphabet?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15510/what-is-the-shortest-string-that-contains-all-permutations-of-an-alphabet)

How can one create a list of numbers so that by taking $n$ consecutive elements from that list, it is possible get every permutation of numbers from 1 to $n$?

I'll explain myself:

The shortest list that contains every permutation of the numbers from 1 to 2 is:
$$1, 2, 1$$
It contains (1, 2) and (2, 1).

With numbers from 1 to 3, it would look like something like this:
$$1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1$$
It contains (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), …

Note: I'm not sure that this is the shortest list possible.

Is there any way to find the smallest list for numbers from 1 to $n$?

Comment: dup? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15510/what-is-the-shortest-string-that-contains-all-permutations-of-an-alphabet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for de Bruijn sequences. That search term should find you what you want.

Comment: Not quite. In de Bruijn sequences every possible _word_ of length $n$ occurs as subword, here only permutations (words without repetition) are considered. The "obvious lower bound" $n!+(n-1)$ cannot always be attained here, for instance a word of length $8$ in $3$ letters of which any successive triplet is distinct can contain only $3$ distinct permutations. So indeed one needs length $9$ for $n=3$.

Comment: +1 since your answer shows that there is probably no "trivial" answer and one has to dig a little deeper.

Comment: @Marc, you're right. I read the question quickly and carelessly.

Answer (score 1):

A reference: http://people.inf.ethz.ch/zeugen/papers/zal_ipl11_perms.pdf

Comment: The reference discusses a slightly different problem in which permutations are required to appear as subsequences, but not necessarily consecutive subsequences as is here the case.