# What is the shortest digit sequence containing all 4 digits sequences?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let's consider all 4 digits sequences:

```
0000
0001
0002
...
9999
```

Obviously there is a large sequence containing all of them as substrings (the concatenation of all of them).

My question is, what is the length of the smallest possible such sequence (since the minimum is attained)?

For 1 digit, the answer is clearly :

```
0123456789
```

(or any permutation).

For 2 digits numbers, it it can be shortened, since "001" contains both "00" and "01".

But I have no clue on how to get to a definitive answer.

I spotted [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15510/what-is-the-shortest-string-that-contains-all-permutations-of-an-alphabet), but I'm not interested in the permutations of the alphabet, but 4-sequences.

Comment: do you know if there is a known answer to find, or has it otherwise cropped up?  If we do find a short representation, I wonder how it could be proved to be the shortest.

Comment: I actually don't know. I know the answer exists, but I'm not sure there is a constructive one, or even a computable one

Comment: I agree there is an answer, it is maybe possible to get the 2 digit solution with a desktop computer - 4 digits, I don't know though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very closed to [De Bruijn sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence).

---

Let's call $A$ your alphabet (for decimal numbers $A=\{0,\ldots,9\}$) and $n$ the length of the contained sequences. We look for sequences containing all elements as (possibly) *cyclic* substring.

Consider the digraph $G = (V,E)$, where:

$$V=A^{n-1}$$
$$E=\{((u_1, \ldots, u_{n-1}), (u_2, \ldots, u_{n-1}, v)), (u_1,\ldots, u_{n-1},v \in A^n\}$$

Then sequences containing all elements of $A^n$ as substring are exactly walks in $G$ going through every edge.

Each node has an in and out degree of $|A|$, so this graph has an Eulerian cycle, which leads to a sequence of length $|A|^n$ minimal possible.

---

If we delete the cycle, the same graph still works. However, the minimal length we get is now the cost of writing the $n-1$ first letters plus the $|E|$ edges, i.e. $n-1+|A|^n$. For $n=4$, $A=\{0,\ldots,9\}$, we get $10003$.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks.

Comment: Surprisingly short by the way. In three hours I can break a 4 digits pin ;)

Comment: Found a python script but strangely it outputs 10,000 symbols for 4 digits: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence `print(len(de_bruijn(10, 4))` -> `10000` and you get 3 more. Where's the catch?

Comment: It doesn't wrap around, so `000` at the end are missing. I wonder how it could be fixed to print the correct sequence for this problem.