# possibilities for entry code of a building

Tags: calculus, probability

> **Exercice** True or Flase
>
> The entry code in a building consists of four digits
> As this building is located in Paris, some occupants want the selected code contains the number "$75$".
> Then there would be $168$ different possible codes.

My thoughts:

since the code is going to be :

$$75xy\quad x75y\quad  \text{or} \quad  xy75 \quad  \text{with}\quad x,y \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 \}$$
then

- $75xy$ gives us $8\times8$ possibitlies
- $x75y$ gives us $10\times 8$ possibitlies
- $xy75$ gives us $10\times 8$ possibitlies

thus there as possibilities $8\times8+10\times 8+10\times 8=224$

Comment: "As this building is located in Paris"?????

Comment: Probably the exercise intends the four digit to be all different. In that case you have $7\times8\times3=168$ possible codes.

Comment: Why aren't your three cases equally numerous? Did you neglect to say first digit can't be 0? Confusing all around. Why assume four different digits? Please edit. BTW: Paris is French "Department" 75. Also 'French 75' is (deservedly obscure) cocktail.

Comment: @Aretino you said : $7\times8\times3=168$  could u explain that

Comment: I guess 3 positions for '75' then pick two more different numbers.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357296/puzzle-a-spy-and-the-keypad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use 7 and 5 you have eight digits left and there are $8\times7$ ways to choose from them the other two digits. As you wrote, there are three possible arrangements for these digits ($75xy$, $x75y$ and $xy75$) so the total number of codes is $56\times3$.